# Reading data from firebase database with multiple child paths

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read the data from the database in the picture shown. I can read the data just fine when there is only one child extending (the restaurant child). However, when I added another child (reviews), my code shown by ** could not read the database anymore and just shows a blank. The Restaurant class just contains getters and setters. Does anyone have a solution for me where it allows me to read the 'restaurant path' only from this code? (my other code not show here would read the reviews path)

[Data from firebase database here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzsjE.jpg)

```
public class Info extends Fragment {

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    String userID;

    private TextView resNameChange, statusChange;

    public Info() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info, container, false);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userID = user.getUid();

        resNameChange = rootView.findViewById(R.id.resNameChange);
        statusChange = rootView.findViewById(R.id.statusChange);

        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                showData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            RestaurantInformation resInfo = new RestaurantInformation();

//****** CODE THAT READS THE PATH AND GET THE DATA *******
            resInfo.setResName(ds.child(userID).getValue(RestaurantInformation.class).getResName());
            resInfo.setStatus(ds.child(userID).getValue(RestaurantInformation.class).getStatus());
//**********************************************************

            resNameChange.setText(resInfo.getResName());
            statusChange.setText(resInfo.getStatus());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference restaurantsRef = rootRef.child("restaurants");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String resName = ds.child("resName").getValue(String.class);
            String status = ds.child("status").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", resName + " / " + status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
restaurantsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
tbfgb / gfdbfbdf
hello / there
```

Comment: It's okay, instead of trying to read the database with this code, I've just changed the structure of my database to be read more easily. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: If you have changed the database structure, the code above will not help you. Did my answer helped you?

Comment: well I didnt use it sorry.